# NullPointerException on (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Tags: android, baseadapter

I have a main activity that loads three tabs when the user opens the app. All the tabs have ListViews populated from an external database, so it takes a couple of seconds to download and display everything. Of course, you don't have to wait for all data to be downloaded to use the app.

Sometimes, I get a NullPointerException on this line:

```
this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

This seem to happen only when I exit the app before everything was downloaded, but not always, like 1 out of 3. However, this might not be right, because as you see below I check to see if there was any data downloaded before calling the adapter, and the result has always the same size(7) which means the download was successful, but for some reason the LayoutInflater goes to null.

**DownloadAsynctask:**

```
public class DownloadNewsfeed extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {            

            Log.i("SIZE", result.size() + "");
            if (result.size() == 0) {
                (...)
            } else {
                myadapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), arr_userid, arr_event, arr_subject, arr_date, arr_result, arr_username, arr_photo, arr_timediff);
                lv.setAdapter(myadapter);
            }
        }

@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() { 
          (...)
          return arr_userid;
        }

@Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
            (...)
      }
    }
```

**Adapter**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

        public Context context;
        ArrayList<String> arr_userid = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arr_event = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arr_subject = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arr_date = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arr_result = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arr_username = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arr_photo = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> arr_timediff = new ArrayList<String>();

        public LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arr_userid, ArrayList<String> arr_event, ArrayList<String> arr_subject, 
                ArrayList<String> arr_date, ArrayList<String> arr_result, ArrayList<String> arr_username, ArrayList<String> arr_photo,
                 ArrayList<String> arr_timediff) {
            super();

            this.context = context;
            this.arr_userid = arr_userid;
            this.arr_event = arr_event;
            this.arr_subject = arr_subject;
            this.arr_date = arr_date;
            this.arr_result = arr_result;
            this.arr_username = arr_username;
            this.arr_photo = arr_photo;
            this.arr_timediff = arr_timediff;

            this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); //**NULLPOINTER**
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arr_userid.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public class ViewHolder
        {
            ImageView image;
            TextView tv_name, tv_date, tv_text, tv_text2;
            LinearLayout row;
        }

@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView==null)
            {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsfeed_listitem_new, null);

                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_user);
                holder.tv_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
                holder.tv_text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_text2);
                holder.tv_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
                holder.tv_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
                holder.row = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lineItem);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
                holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

                holder.tv_text.setText(arr_event.get(position) + ":");
                holder.tv_text2.setText(arr_result.get(position));

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your context is null.

Comment: Declare and define a context variable in your activity onCreate() or onAttach() if you are using fragment and pass it at the time of Adapter creation. i.e. replace getActivity by context variable on adapter creation.

Comment: So all I need to do is declare  `Context ctx;` then in onCreate() declare `ctx = getActivity();` and call the adapter as `myadapter = new MyAdapter(ctx, arr_userid, ...)`?

Answer (score 0):

Once you exit the app it makes no sense to do any more work. `getActivity()` will return `null` after the Activity has been destroyed. Perform a null check before you proceed:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {            
    if (getActivity() == null) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Activity ended prematurely.");
        return;
    }

    Log.i("SIZE", result.size() + "");
    if (result.size() == 0) {
        (...)
    } else {
        myadapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), arr_userid, arr_event, arr_subject, arr_date, arr_result, arr_username, arr_photo, arr_timediff);
        lv.setAdapter(myadapter);
    }
}
```

Unrelated note: Consider creating a Holder for newsfeed items such as this:

```
public class NewsfeedItem {
    String userid;
    String event;
    String subject;
    String date;
    String result;
    String username;
    String photo;
    String timediff;

    public NewsfeedItem() {}
}
```

This will save you from having a ton of `ArrayList`s in favor of having only one.